# Find the marginal distribution of a bernouilli and continuous joint distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, solution-verification

I need to find the following. Is the method right?

> Find $f_X(x), f_Y(y)$ if the joint distribution in $(x,y)$ is given:
>
> $$\frac{p^x(1-p)^{1-x}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} \exp \left( -\frac{(y-\alpha- \beta x)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$$
>
> if $x\in \{ 0,1\}$ and $0$ if not.

#### Marginalizing $x$ out using $\displaystyle \sum_{x\in \{ 0,1\}}$

$$f_Y(y) = \frac{1-p}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} \exp \left( -\frac{(y-\alpha)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) + \frac{p}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} \exp \left( -\frac{(y-\alpha- \beta)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$$

#### Marginalizing $y$ out using $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \text{d}y$

$$f_X(x) = \frac{p^x(1-p)^{1-x}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp \left( -\frac{(y-\alpha- \beta x)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) \text{d}y$$

Can I use the gamma function (after the relevant transformation) to simplify this as:
$$f_X(x) = p^x(1-p)^{1-x}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These seem okay to me (assuming, and this seems reasonable, that the range of $Y$ is all $\mathbb{R}$.).

**Note**: You can *always* gain confidence that a marginal has been derived correctly, by checking that it satisfies the properties of being a probability distribution (that is, it is non-negative and "integrates" to 1). Both of the marginals you derived satisfy this.

And, in passing, because we are dealing with a Gaussian integral with parameters $\mu{}={}\alpha{}+{}\beta x$ and $\sigma^2$, we must have

$$
f_X(x) = \frac{p^x(1-p)^{1-x}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp \left( -\frac{(y-\alpha- \beta x)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) \text{d}y{}={}\frac{p^x(1-p)^{1-x}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma{}={}p^x(1-p)^{1-x}\,.
$$